# How to implement printing in chrome pacakaged app created from GWT Application.?

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-app

I have integrated the GWT application with Chrome packaged app with help of DirectLinkerinstaller like the code below:

```
public class CSPCompatibleLinker extends DirectInstallLinker {
    @Override
    protected String getJsInstallLocation(LinkerContext context) {
        return "com/google/gwt/core/ext/linker/impl/installLocationMainWindow.js";
    }
}
```

But now I want to call print function from Chrome packaged app. When I call `window.print()` it allows me to print current window, but I need to open a new separate window and print that.

Could you anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer anything about GWT or DirectLinkerinstaller, but here's an answer about Chrome Apps, assuming that's what you're asking about:

You use the chrome.app.window.create API to create a window. Then, you can call the print method for that window.

In my apps, I seldom want to print what's in a window, but rather something I've generated specifically for printing. For that, I create a PDF with jsPDF (Google it), which works well. Then I display the PDF in a window, and let the user print the PDF (or save it).

Comment: Star https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131279 for more on printing in Chrome Apps.